# Google Maps SDK for iOS trying to run on iOS 4.3

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I successfully integrated the `sdk` with my app.
My app is intended to run with `Google Maps sdk for iOS6`, 
and with Apple `UIMapKit` for `iOS` 4.3 and 5.x . 
Since I added the `google maps` framework, 
ios 4.3 won't run anymore. 
I changed the `GLKit.framework` and `GoogleMaps.framework` to "optional", 
and I get `dyld: Symbol not found: _NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication` before the app even starts. 
need your help :-)

Comment: hi, did you integrate it in your app following this documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start ?

Comment: of course. it's already working in ios6 and not crushing on ios5

Comment: but i didn't get any response yet after applying for API key!! any idea why is it so ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity why are you still supporting 4.3?  If you look at current usage it's hardly used by anyone.

Comment: @Dancreek: About 8% of my users (in the last month) were using 4.x, so I'd prefer not to cut them off if I can.

Answer (score 3):

My app runs okay on iOS 4.3, with `GLKit.framework` and `GoogleMaps.framework` set to optional, and if I remove all calls to the Google API.

Could the reference to `NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication` be caused by some of your other code or other frameworks?

**UPDATE:**

Actually the above is wrong. I had forgotten to include the `-ObjC` linker flag in step 7 of [the instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project). Without the `-ObjC` the app is able to run fine on iOS 4.3. Without the `-ObjC` flag on iOS 6 the call to `[GMSServices provideAPIKey]` succeeds, but the call to `[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:camera:]` fails silently (returns nil), so this isn't an option.

With the `-ObjC` flag in place, on iOS 4.3 I get the same error about `_NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication`.

I tried changing `-ObjC` to `-force_load $(PROJECT_DIR)/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps`, to only force loading of the Google Maps API and not other libraries, but it still fails on iOS 4.3.

I presume that the `-ObjC` or `-force_load` are overriding the setting to make `GoogleMaps.framework` optional.

Also, on iOS 5.0 I get a similar error about `_NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey`. I'm presuming it would work on iOS 5.1, though. @tomeron11, what version of 5.x were you testing with?

**UPDATE 2:**

It feels like a horrible hack, but adding the following to one of the .m files in the project allows it to work on iOS 5.0:

```
NSString* const NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey = @"NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey";
```

This doesn't *seem* to cause a problem on iOS 6.0, even though the symbol will have been defined twice, although I'm not sure if it can be trusted.

For iOS 4.3 I tried doing the equivalent, by adding:

```
NSString* const NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication = 
    @"NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication";
```

This stops the error about `_NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication`, but then I get the following error instead:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableOrderedSet
```

I'm not sure if there is a way to fool the linker into seeing a dummy version of NSMutableOrderedSet on iOS 4.3.

**UPDATE 3:**

The SDK documentation says that the [minimum supported platform is iOS 5.1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/intro#supported_platforms).

Google have [closed the bug report as WontFix](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4750#c1), so it seems there will be no way to get it to work on 5.0 or below.

**UPDATE 4:**

Google have [reopened the bug as an Enhancement](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4750#c4).

**UPDATE 5:**

The latest version 1.1.0 of the SDK now no longer crashes on startup on iOS 5.0.

However, [Google will not be fixing the crash on iOS 4.x](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4750#c6).

Since the SDK only officially supports iOS 5.1+, although it no longer crashes on startup on iOS 5.0, if you try to create a `GMSMapView` then it crashes with an error message:

> Google Maps SDK for iOS only supports iOS 5.1+

If you use the hack which used to make it not crash on startup on 5.0, ie this:

```
NSString* const NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey = @"NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey";
```

Then the SDK will run on iOS 5.0. It seems to work, but it's probably not a good idea, as it is not officially supported by Google.

Comment: I raised this as a bug report on Google's issue tracker here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4750

Comment: on 5.0 it's not working. i get "dyld: Symbol not found: _NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey". sorry about the miss-info.

Comment: iOS6 up now unfortunately for people with stubborn clients

Comment: iOS5 support was dropped with the release of SDK version 1.5. Backwards compatible version here: `pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-SDK', '~> 1.4.3'`

Answer (score 0):

I Foundation.framework and UIKit.framework(UIActivityViewController crashed in 1.5 GMSdk too.....) set in mode "option" (weak a no seen in combobox). NSMutableOrdererSet and NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey situated in this framework component.
I don`t check how work this solution on ios less 5.0, but from 5.0 to 6.0 not crashed, or please not use Google Map SDK from 5 to 6 instead of this MKMapView!

P.S. Sorry my bad english!