# Can I link GoogleMaps SDK for iOS with a linker flag other than -ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using GoogleMapsSDK, and Parse's framework.

If I use them together, a bug in Parse triggers required facebook keys because of the linker flag -ObjC.  This is a well documented problem on Parse's forums and on here for other frameworks besides GoogleMaps, and the general solution is to import Facebook SDK.  I'm not interested in using facebook in any way, and I'd prefer not to add it to my project, so if there's a different way that I can call the linker flag it would be most appreciated.

Some of the answers say something about -force_load as opposed to -ObjC but it requires some additional info that I'm not sure how to get.

**IN A SENTENCE:**

Please provide an exact -force_load that will work with the GoogleMapsSDK to avoid using the linker flag -ObjC

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Back when I was testing the original version 1.0 of the SDK I tried using this:

```
-force_load $(PROJECT_DIR)/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps
```

More details on what I was trying [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14030418/google-maps-sdk-for-ios-trying-to-run-on-ios-4-3).

It seemed to work at the time, although it caused problems with Google's fix to allow the SDK to not crash on startup with iOS 5.0 with SDK 1.1.0 ([see here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4750#c7)), and I haven't tried it since, so it might not work with the current version.

You might need to adjust the `-force_load` a bit depending on your path to the GoogleMaps framework relative to your project directory.

Can you provide a link to the bug reports with Parse and `-ObjC`? I am using the Google Maps SDK with `-ObjC` and Parse (but not with Facebook), and haven't had any problems. However I'd be interested in knowing what to look out for in case I want to do more with Parse in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working.  I tried a lot of different directory pathways, and it just doesn't go through?

Links:
https://parse.com/questions/use-parse-with-objc
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457136/parse-for-ios-errors-when-trying-to-run-the-app
https://www.parse.com/questions/using-the-parse-ios-sdk-without-including-the-facebook-sdk
https://parse.com/questions/cocoapods-incompatibility